# Games in steam too slow

Tags: graphic-drivers, steam

a few months ago I installed some stuff in my elementary OS. I don't remember exactly what I did (I have tried to reverse the things), but it fumbled Steam. Now the Steam is too slow (I think that is something related with graphic parameters). Some one could help me?

ASUS S46C

```
descrição: VGA compatible controller
   produto: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   fabricante: Intel Corporation
   ID físico: 2
   informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
   versão: 09
   largura: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuração: driver=i915 latency=0
   recursos: irq:46 memória:f7800000-f7bfffff memória:e0000000-efffffff porta de E/S:f000(tamanho=64)
```

glxinfo | grep render

```
direct rendering: Yes

GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 

OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)

GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,
```

Comment: I believe this model also has an Nvidia card? Can you confirm this with `lspci`. Did you install *Bumblebee* **or** *nvidia-prime*?

Comment: Hi! No, have a Intel chipset. And I didn't install bumblebee or nvidia-prime. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam games too slow](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/steam-games-too-slow)